# java.lang.nullPointerException Error

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Estou fazendo um exercício de **Java** e ele requer que eu crie uma nota do produto vendido, contendo números aleatórios mais as três primeiras letras do cliente como código do produto, mas quando tento gerar a nota ganho esse **erro**.

```
public Compra(){
     String s = cliente.getNome();
     String sub = s.substring(0, 4);
     String num = String.valueOf((int)(Math.random()*10000+100));
     numero = num + sub;
}
```

EDIT
Classe Compra completa

```
public class Compra{
    private String numero;
    private Cliente cliente;
    private Vendedor vendedor;
    private double precoOriginal;
    private double desconto;
    private double preco;

    public Compra(double pO, double ds, double pF, Cliente client){        

        String s = cliente.getNome();
        String sub = s.substring(0, 4);
        String num = String.valueOf((int)(Math.random()*10000+100));
        numero = num + sub;

        precoOriginal = pO;
        desconto = ds;
        preco = pF;
        cliente = client;
    }
    public Compra(double prO, double dst, double prF, Cliente client, Vendedor vend){

        precoOriginal = prO;
        desconto = dst;
        preco = prF;
        cliente = client;
        vendedor = vend;
    }
    // CLASSE PARA TESTAR O NUMERO(CODIGO)
    public Compra(){
        String s = cliente.getNome();
        String sub = s.substring(0, 4);
        String num = String.valueOf((int)(Math.random()*10000+100));
        numero = num + sub;
    }

    public void adDesconto(double desct){
        preco = preco - (preco * desct);

    }
    public void setVendedor(Vendedor vend){
        vendedor = vend;
    }
}
```

Comment: Aonde acontece o erro, em qual linha ??? ou qual parte do código ?

Comment: Se é nesse construtor que ocorre o erro, então há duas possibildiades: ou `cliente` é nulo, ou `s` é nulo.

Comment: a linha  String s = cliente.getNome(); é a origem do erro.

Comment: e ao mesmo tempo o blueJ abre o terminal window e manda o seguinte erro: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Compra.<init>(Compra.java:31)

Comment: cliente deve ser uma classe sem instanciação (`new`)... outro local que pode acontecer erros é s.substring primeiro verifica se o lenght é `>= 4` ...

Comment: @user3511983, edite o post e coloque a código por completo!

Comment: postei o codigo completo

Comment: Error: 
`public Compra(double pO, double ds, double pF, Cliente client)` e tem um `private Cliente cliente`, os nomes `client` é diferente de `cliente` na variavel local da classe ...

Comment: @Fúlvio o erro continua o mesmo...

Comment: @user3511983 eu fiz uma ligeira alteração na sua classe, porque, você tem que passar do construtor para dentro dela, e no construtor sem paramentro tem que dar um new Cliente ... (mesmo assim acredito que a lógica deve ser outra)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solução:**

```
public class Compra{
    private String numero;
    private Cliente cliente;
    private Vendedor vendedor;
    private double precoOriginal;
    private double desconto;
    private double preco;

    public Compra(double pO, double ds, double pF, Cliente client){        
        cliente = client;
        String s = cliente.getNome();
        String sub = s.substring(0, 4);
        String num = String.valueOf((int)(Math.random()*10000+100));
        numero = num + sub;

        precoOriginal = pO;
        desconto = ds;
        preco = pF;
        cliente = client;
    }
    public Compra(double prO, double dst, double prF, Cliente client, Vendedor vend){
        cliente = client;
        vendedor = vend;
        precoOriginal = prO;
        desconto = dst;
        preco = prF;
        cliente = client;
        vendedor = vend;
    }
    // CLASSE PARA TESTAR O NUMERO(CODIGO)
    public Compra(){
        cliente = new Cliente();            
           String s = cliente.getNome();
        if (s != null){  
           String sub = s.substring(0, 4);
        }
        String num = String.valueOf((int)(Math.random()*10000+100));
        numero = num + sub;
    }

    public void adDesconto(double desct){
        preco = preco - (preco * desct);

    }
    public void setVendedor(Vendedor vend){
        vendedor = vend;
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @Fúlvio , me ajudou bastante, mas agora aparece um erro ao compilar, na linha  cliente = new Cliente(); , "No suitable constructor found for Cliente()

Comment: este seria o meu construtor da classe cliente, caso ajude. public Cliente(String nm){
        this.nome = nm;
        this.endereco = new Endereco();
    }

Comment: Então como eu não vi a classe Cliente ele deve ter construtor com paramentro então ali se tem que colocar os dados ... o Erro é porque Cliente(aqui tem parametros), por favor @user3511983 observe isso

Comment: cliente = new Cliente("passa aqui um valor de string") que pode ser "" ou "seu nome" ou "seu valor" ... etc ...

Comment: ok Fulvio, muito obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 1):

Falta você instanciar as classes vendedor, pois só a referencia ao objeto e não o objeto em si
ele ainda nao existe ate você instanciar ele com o comando new.
Basta fazer igual ao exemplo

```
vendedor = new Vendedor();
```